# Download Multiple Documents from share point 2013 Document Library

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-server, custom-actions

I need to download multiple documents from SharePoint document library from a custom ribbon button.

Do we have any free source code such as Devianpoint to achieve this.

I tried deploying the WSP, as shown in following URL, but it doesn't seem to work on share point 2013 since the ribbon button is grayed out.

http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2010/05/08/sharepoint-2010-download-as-zip-file-custom-ribbon-action.aspx

Comment: Can you add XML configuration which you have added for Ribbon?

Comment: got the same requirement. Any progress or new solution proposal for this subject?